# Running multiple asynchronous function and get the returned value of each function

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I was trying to create a function which can run multiple processes asynchronous and will send the response. Since `multiprocessing.Process()` do not return the response, I thought of creating a function as:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def async_call(func_list):
    """
    Runs the list of function asynchronously.

    :param func_list: Expects list of lists to be of format
        [[func1, args1, kwargs1], [func2, args2, kwargs2], ...]
    :return: List of output of the functions
        [output1, output2, ...]
    """
    response_list = []
    def worker(function, f_args, f_kwargs, response_list):
        """
        Runs the function and appends the output to list
        """
        response = function(*f_args, **f_kwargs)
        response_list.append(response)

    processes = [Process(target=worker, args=(func, args, kwargs, response_list)) \
                    for func, args, kwargs in func_list]

    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    return response_list
```

Within this function, I call `worker` asynchronously which accepts additional parameter as `list`. Since, lists are passed as reference, I thought I can append the response of actual function within the list. And `async_call` will return me the response of all the function.

But this is not behaving the way I expected. Value gets appended to the `list` within the `worker()`, but outside the worker `response_list` list remains empty.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? And, is there any alternative to achieve what I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Daniel's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40536317/2063361), objects can not be directly shared between the processes. However, [*multiprocessing*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library provides *Queues* and *Pipes* as communication channel between processes. (Read [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) for more details)

Here is the function I created using [`multiprocessing.Queue()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue):

```
def async_call(func_list):
    """
    Runs the list of function asynchronously.

    :param func_list: Expects list of lists to be of format
        [[func1, args1, kwargs1], [func2, args2, kwargs2], ...]
    :return: List of output of the functions
        [output1, output2, ...]
    """
    def worker(function, f_args, f_kwargs, queue, index):
        """
        Runs the function and appends the output to list, and the Exception in the case of error
        """
        response = {
            'index': index,  # For tracking the index of each function in actual list.
                             # Since, this function is called asynchronously, order in
                             # queue may differ
            'data': None,
            'error': None
        }

        # Handle error in the function call
        try:
            response['data'] = function(*f_args, **f_kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            response['error'] = e  # send back the exception along with the queue

        queue.put(response)
    queue = Queue()
    processes = [Process(target=worker, args=(func, args, kwargs, queue, i)) \
                    for i, (func, args, kwargs) in enumerate(func_list)]
    
    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    response_list = []
    for process in processes:
        # Wait for process to finish
        process.join()

        # Get back the response from the queue
        response = queue.get()
        if response['error']:
            raise response['error']   # Raise exception if the function call failed
        response_list.append(response)

    return [content['data'] for content in sorted(response_list, key=lambda x: x['index'])]
```

Sample run:

```
def my_sum(x, y):
    return x + y

def your_mul(x, y):
    return x*y

my_func_list = [[my_sum, [1], {'y': 2}], [your_mul, [], {'x':1, 'y':2}]]

async_call(my_func_list)
# Value returned: [3, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't share objects directly across processes. You need to use one of the classes especially designed for communicating values, Queue and Pipe; see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).