# Multiprocessing shared variable not updating

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to update a shared variable (numpy array in a namespace) when using the multiprocessing module. However, the variable is not updated and I dont understand why.

Here is a sample code to illustrate this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import numpy as np

chunk_size = 15
arr_length = 1000
jobs = []
namespace = Manager().Namespace()
namespace.arr = np.zeros(arr_length)
nb_chunk = arr_length/chunk_size + 1


def foo(i, ns):
    from_idx = chunk_size*i
    to_idx = min(arr_length, chunk_size*(i+1))
    ns.arr[from_idx:to_idx] = np.random.randint(0, 100, to_idx-from_idx)

for i in np.arange(nb_chunk):
    p = Process(target=foo, args=(i, namespace))
    p.start()
    jobs.append(p)
for i in np.arange(nb_chunk):
    jobs[i].join()

print namespace.arr[:10]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `Manager().Namespace()` object doesn't notice that you're changing anything using `ns.arr[from_idx:to_idx] = ...` (as you're working on a inner data structure) and thus doesn't propagate to the other processes.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436757/how-does-multiprocessing-manager-work-in-python) explains very good what's going on here.

To fix it, create the list as a `Manager().List()` and pass this list to the processes, so that `ns[from_idx:to_idx] = ...` is recognized as a change and is propagated to the processes:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import numpy as np

chunk_size = 15
arr_length = 1000
jobs = []
arr = Manager().list([0] * arr_length)

nb_chunk = arr_length/chunk_size + 1


def foo(i, ns):
    from_idx = chunk_size*i
    to_idx = min(arr_length, chunk_size*(i+1))
    ns[from_idx:to_idx] = np.random.randint(0, 100, to_idx-from_idx)

for i in np.arange(nb_chunk):
    p = Process(target=foo, args=(i, arr))
    p.start()
    jobs.append(p)
for i in np.arange(nb_chunk):
    jobs[i].join()

print arr[:10]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not share in-built objects like `list`, `dict` across processes in Python. In order to share data between process, [Python's multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) provide two data structure:

- [`Queue()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue)
- [`Pipe()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe)

Also read: [Exchanging objects between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)

Comment: ok, but how could I take advantage that in each process, I do not access the same memory space of the array ?

Comment: Similar to your current code, by passing them as an argument to function (`foo()` in your case). You may refer [Running multiple asynchronous function and get the returned value of each function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536287/running-multiple-asynchronous-function-and-get-the-returned-value-of-each-functi), the question I asked in the past. It is having answer with the usage of `Queue`